# I am looking to exit a handler and go back to activity code when it has done its job

Tags: android, timer, handler, runnable, countdown

I have been trying to figure out how to make a countdown timer using 'handler()' and i still don't know how to make it so the app will execute the line "Finished" when the countdown hits 0.

I am after whatever line of code is required for me to enter in the 'UpdateGUI()' to exit the runnable and go back to the main activity to display "Finished".

I have not been coding very long, so maybe it is an obvious answer, but I can't find it on any threads on this page...

Some help would be much appreciated :-)

Thank you

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int i = 10;
    TextView tv;
    final Handler myHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

                Timer myTimer = new Timer();
                myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                   @Override
                    public void run() {
                        UpdateGUI();
                    }
                }, 0, 1000);
                tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                tv.setText("Finished");
            }
        });
    }

    private void UpdateGUI() {
        if (i == 0) {
            //this is where i need to enter the code!!
        }
        else
            i--;
        myHandler.post(myRunnable);
    }

    final Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           tv.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly in case you need to run your runnable after some period of time use Handler method **postDelayed(runnable, timeOutInMillis)**

UPDATE: example of handler timer

```
int timesRun;
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        runTimer();
        i++;
    }
};  

// call it in button callback
  public void runTimer(){
      // update your timer here
      if (i != 10) // if 10 seconds not passed run it one more time
      handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000); // run every second
  }
```

Note that this is not the most elegant way to do this, but still, it should work

Comment: Thank you for your response. Does that mean the runnable will only run for 'x' seconds and then go back to main activity?

Comment: I woiuld like the runnable to start when the button is pressed, the runnable will then give a 10 seconds countdown, and then when the runnable is finished, i would like the text to say "Finished" and then the rest of the app will continue from there in main activity

Comment: @DogBarrett I`ve added the example

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll give that a crack